# Excel VBA get Font Names of a selected Chart

Tags: excel, fonts

I have a short Sub() which gets the names of a few chart elements. In my example all chart elements of the selected chart are +Body which, according to Excel Themes is Calibri. No surprise there but when I run this code I get different results, for the title I get +mn-lt and for other chart elements I get Calibri. Can I get the name (Calibri) instead of +mn-lt? Otherwise I would always need to manually check in an Excel Workbook what +Body refers to. Alternatively, maybe I can query from VBA which Font +Body is for the current Workbook.

```
Sub GetFontNamesOfChart()
Dim cht As Chart

If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set cht = ActiveChart
Debug.Print "Title:  " & cht.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name
Debug.Print "y-Axis: " & cht.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Name
Debug.Print "x-Axis: " & cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Name
If cht.HasLegend = True Then
   Debug.Print "Legend: " & cht.Legend.Font.Name
End If
If cht.Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True Then
   Debug.Print "xTitle: " & cht.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Font.Name
End If
End Sub
```

The output is in my case:

```
Title:  +mn-lt
y-Axis: Calibri
x-Axis: Calibri
Legend: Calibri
xTitle: Calibri
```

The desired output is:

```
Title:  Calibri
y-Axis: Calibri
x-Axis: Calibri
Legend: Calibri
xTitle: Calibri
```